# Multi-variable Fixed Point Iteration Command?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerics

We want to find the zeros of a multi-dimensional function

```
  f[x_, y_] = {x + 1/4 (-Cos[x] + Sin[y]), x - y - Sin[y]/4}
```

To find the zeros, we can initialize and show the iterates using [*FindRoot*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
  {res, {stxy}} = Reap[FindRoot[f[x, y], {{x, -1}, {y, -1}}, StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]]
```

However, if we want to perform [*Multi-variable Fixed Point Iteration*](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat461/lecture22.pdf), we can write $X = G(x)$

```
  fg[x_,y_] = {-1/4(Sin[x} + Cos[y],-1/4(Sin[x] + 2 Cos[y]}
```

Is there a way to use [*FixedPointList*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) or another  function to actually perform the FPI?

Note: I can certainly do this using [*Table*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), but thought there is likely a built-in method.

Comment: The command `FixedPointList` has syntax `FixedPointList[f, expr]` where `f` can be _anything_ that will be applied to `expr` repeatedly, and `expr` can also be _any_ Mathematica expression. It is not limited to a single variable.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: I tried using that, had a slight issue with syntax and gave up, rats! Thanks for that comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := {x + 1/4 (-Cos[x] + Sin[y]), x - y - Sin[y]/4}
g[x_, y_] := {-1/4 (Sin[y] - Cos[x]), x - Sin[y]/4}

(* Try changing x0, y0 to get another point if one exists. *)
(* The '100' is a limit on the number of iterations, increase if desired *)
fp = With[{x0 = 1, y0 = 1}, FixedPoint[g @@ # &, N[{x0, y0}], 100]]

(* result {0.204129, 0.163449} *)

f @@ fp

(* result: {0., -2.77556*10^-17} *)
```

You can also use `FixedPointList` to get the path for all iterations. The black vector field is your multi-dimensional function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, and the red arrows show the successive $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})=G(x_i,y_i)$ converging to a root of $F$ at $(x_\infty,y_\infty)$. I've done it for five steps for clarity:

```
fp = With[{x0 = 1, y0 = 1, steps = 5}, FixedPointList[g @@ # &, N[{x0, y0}], steps]]
Show[
 VectorPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
 , Graphics[{Thick, Red, Arrow /@ Partition[fp, 2, 1]}]
]
```

[image: vector field with fixed point iteration]

... and since no answer is complete without some animation, this allows you to interactively set the starting point:

```
Manipulate[
 fp = With[{x0 = p[[1]], y0 = p[[2]], steps = 5}, 
   FixedPointList[g @@ # &, N[{x0, y0}], steps]];
 Show[VectorDensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"], 
  Graphics[{Thick, Red, Arrow /@ Partition[fp, 2, 1]}]]
 , {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image: fixed point vector density plot animation]

Comment: Nice animation. I wonder if there is a way to bound the points where there is convergence and also to calculate the convergence rate based on the points being generated - those would be really useful? By the way, how do you capture the animation in order to post it?

Comment: I use ScreenToGif. I guess you could get a rate based on the length the jumps from point to point. With the above paths recorded in `fp` that would look like this: `ListLinePlot[Norm[Subtract @@ #] & /@ Partition[fp, 2, 1]]`

Comment: This will stop when either 1000 iterations are reached, or the length of the jump from point to point drops below 0.01 for example: `NestWhileList[g @@ # &, N@{1, 1}, Norm[#2 - #1] > 0.01 &, 2, 1000]`

Comment: Both of those are very useful. Thank you!